# VBA macro for visio that will display shape data on an html page

Tags: vba, visio

I have a complex network diagram and I have connected the "important" shapes to a database.  What I can't find is a way to display the shape data when I save the diagram as html.  Using any combination of options in the save as, produces only a basic vertical menu area on the left side, that does exactly NOTHING in IE.
Chrome gives me a brief tool-tip, and the menu will re-display the page. Firefox does best, I get a pan and zoom area in the left side menu.  There is even a "Details" area below that with the comments "Ctl+Click to see shape data".  It does not work on any of the shapes that actually have data.

I'm beginning to think its a blocked content restriction in the browser.  Ideas please!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this add-in [HTML Export](http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/) by [Nikolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929187/nikolay)
[image]
At Nikolay's personal site ([unmanagedvisio.com](http://unmanagedvisio.com/)) you can find few articles about this add-in.

**PS You can't change this shape data when use this add-in !**